# Spring MVC: SessionAttributes and List

Tags: list, session, spring-mvc, attributes

I am facing an issue with spring and it goes as follows:

In SessionAttributes I have an object person with an attribute addresses which is a list. Whenever person is updated via controler, previous entries still remain. So for example if I had in person addresses: old address 1, old address 2, old address 3 and I update person via form to have only one new address, list of addresses becomes: new address 1, old address 2, old address 3 while intended behavior is to have "new address 1" only. I couldn't seem to find a workaround this problem. I am using Spring 3.0.X.

Please find below all related code that shows the issue on hand.

Person.java:

```
package com.convert.dashboard.web.test;

import java.util.List;

public class Person {

private String name;

private Integer age;

private List<String> addresses;

public Person(List<String> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public List<String> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}

public void setAddresses(List<String> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}

}
```

TestController.java

```
package com.convert.dashboard.web.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
@SessionAttributes("person")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ModelAndView xyz() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
    abc.add("old address1");
    abc.add("old address2");
    abc.add("old address3");
    Person person = new Person(abc);
    mav.addObject("person", person);
    mav.setViewName("cForm");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping("/save")
public @ResponseBody
String process(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
    return "<body>" + " Name:" + person.getName() + "  Age: " + person.getAge() + " Addresses: " + person.getAddresses();
}
}
```

cForm.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>populate form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form modelAttribute="person" action="/dashboard/test/save">

<form:hidden path="name" value="X" />
<form:hidden path="age" value="20" />
<form:hidden path="addresses[0]" value="New address" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but by default, the scope of the class is a singleton. Perhaps in your case @Scope("prototype") would be more appropriate?

Comment: Adding @Scope("prototype") does not resolve issue on hand.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the person in the session. It's not a good idea to store something in the session unless it's almost necessary.

Comment: In my scenario it is necessary as I need to carry same object across multiple controllers.

Comment: OK.Maybe you can add a parameter to xyz() like xyz(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) or just xyz(HttpServletRequest request) and then get the object from the request so you don't create a new object but you get the one which is in session.  (I'm not sure if the first one will work). After retrieving it I think you won't eneed to put it back to the model as it is already in the session.

Comment: The first approach does not work xyz(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) with an error "person not in session". As for second suggest, I guess you meant adding HttpServletRequest request to the process function. This does not work with lists in object left unmodified!

Comment: Have a look at the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757198/spring-framework-3-and-session-attributes

Comment: @Javi, I am afraid the issue lies not on having the object in session as pointed out in question you posted earlier, but in how the object is handled with previous list entries retained rather than updated with new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution goes as follows:

By appending an AJAX call on remove on the client side and adding the code below to the controller.

```
    @RequestMapping("/remeveAddress")
    public @ResponseBody String removeElement(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, @RequestParam Integer addressId, Model model){
    person.getAddresses().remove(addressId);
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "{}";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of design issues I would like to address.

1. You are using a single object for both form binding and domain data.  This tends to cause problems exactly like the one you've encountered here.  The problem is not that the form fails to "clear" out the addresses of the session object; the problem is that the session object leaks its data structure to the form, which causes binding problems.
2. The form has knowledge about the contents of the `Person` object.  Specifically, the form expects there to be three addresses in the `person.getAddresses()` list.  Like (1) above, the problem is a leak of the domain structure into the view layer.

I recommend that you create two different "person" classes: one to represent the domain data (the session object), and one to exactly mirror the structure of the form (the form binding object).  Your form will contain fields that map directly to properties in a `PersonForm` class, and in your `TestController` you can take the data from the `PersonForm` and update the session `Person` appropriately.  Then the form inputs don't need to be designed to handle different states of the `Person.addresses` list.

This approach does require a bit more code, but not terribly much, and the savings in form complexity and form/domain decoupling is well worth it.

Comment: I am already familiar with this approach, with the creation of proxy objects to mirror the domain, but the issue with this is that in essence I am replicating the domain object inside the proxy object.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and solved it by introducing an init binder to the controller.
The init binder resets the list of addresses for the session attribute.
Depending on requirements it could do some more sophisticated job.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(HttpSession session) {
    Person person = (Person)session.getAttribute("person");
    person.getAddresses().clear();
}
```

Hope that could help someone else :)

Comment: This does not work for my case as addresses are cleared *every* time controller is visited, which is not intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've faced with the same problem, and I've found a very simple solution.
So you need just to add a hidden field for your list.
Spring conversion service will set empty list from the blank string value of this hidden field :)

You can see the solution below:

```
<input type='hidden' name='addresses' value='' />
```

And after that put your other code:

```
<form:input path="addresses[0]" />
<form:input path="addresses[n]" />
```

---

Notes:
If you need to convert **String** to **List of YourClass**'es, and you haven't own convertors or editors for that.
So make sure that at least [ObjectToObjectConverter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/convert/support/ObjectToObjectConverter.html) can do it, YourClass must have constructor with a **String** arg or the static method **valueOf(String)**.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another possible solution is to use a handler interceptor as follows.

servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/test/**" />
        <bean class="com.convert.dashboard.web.test.PersonInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

PersonInterceptor.java:

```
public class PersonInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        Person person = (Person)request.getSession().getAttribute("person");
        if (person != null)
            person.getAddresses().clear();

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```