# Set session variable spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I set a session object which I can use then in any of my views by using `${variable}` or `${requestScope.variable}`

To be able to use sessions do I need to set `<%@ page session="true" %>` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to access a session variable in your view the easiest way to do it is :

```
${sessionScope.yourVariable}
```

See the [Using Scope Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/) for more info.

If you set `<%@ page session="true">` then the JSP will merge the session scope and at the page scope into a single namespace. Then you can do:

```
${yourVariable}
```

You can put something into the session in a mvc controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMestod(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("testVariable", "Test Values!!");
        return "testJsp";
    }
}
```

Finally, the @SessionAttribute is meant for a specifc use case, and doesn't put variables into the session so that anyone can access them:

Here is how the spring folks describe the functionality of @SessionAttribute:

> The @SessionAttributes works in the
>   same way as the sessionForm of the
>   SimpleFormController. It puts the
>   command (or for the @SessionAttributes
>   any object) in the session for the
>   duration between the first and the
>   last request (most of the time the
>   initial GET and the final POST). After
>   that the stuff is removed.
>
> Each Controller has it's own ModelMap
>   so something put as a
>   @SessionAttributes in controller1
>   isn't available in controller2 and
>   vice versa. For that to work you will
>   have to put stuff on the session
>   manually yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SessionAttributes Annotation.  Check it out at the spring documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)

You can also manually add and remove variables from session with the DefaultSessionAttributeStore [api](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/)