# @SessionAttributes gives HttpSessionRequiredException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using Spring MVC 3.0.5. I am trying to learn how to use `@SessionAttributes`. Here is a sample of my code:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("book")
public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping("/book/bookForm.htm")
    public ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Valid @ModelAttribute("book") Book book, BindingResult result) throws Exception {

        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();

        return new ModelAndView("bookForm", modelMap);
    }

}
```

When I try go to /book/bookForm.htm I am getting the exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Session attribute 'book' required - not found in session
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.raiseSessionRequiredException(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:758)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:356)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

**How could I solve this problem?**

I also have tried following this answer:

[Spring Framework 3 and session attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757198/spring-framework-3-and-session-attributes)

Some questions regarding that answer:

1. The asker's code and the chosen answer's code seem essentially the same... so where is the addition that solved the problem?
2. Trying to read the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html), I cannot understand what this annotation actually does:

**When is the relevant command object being saved on the session? Is it when we enter the controller's method, or when we leave it, or each time we manipulate the content of the command object....? When does the command object start being saved on the session?**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the answer ?  I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the "default method" that's chosen with the Spring annotations is the one that has the least arguments when you invoke your page for the first time.  The more specific the method, the less likely it will be the default one.

If you take your @RequestMapping("/book/bookForm.htm") and place it on a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/book/bookForm.htm")
public ModelAndView setupForm() throws Exception {

    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    // I don't remember the exact syntax here - pretending its a java.util.Map.
    modelMap.put("book", new Book());

    return new ModelAndView("bookForm", modelMap);
}
```

This will be the default because it has the least amount of arguments.  You have to create your form and place it into the session/model and view/model map/kitchen sink (seriously, the RequestMapping parameter combinations are both awesome and ridiculous) on the first request to the page.  After that, the individual methods will be called as appropriate based on the fact that you now actually have the "book" session attribute stored (because it was placed under the "book" key).

Parameter names and values, etc, all determine which method is invoked after the default - it's a really nice and flexible way of configuring a controller to respond to web requests, but it does take some getting used to.

Comment: (1) I do not think what you say about Spring chooses default methods based on how few arguments they have is correct. If this were true, then why would I not just have that setupForm() method that you have written, with no @RequestMapping - it has arguments, so Spring will always choose it? AFAIK Spring chooses methods by their @RequestMapping... (2) "You have to create your form and place it into the session/model... on the first request to the page." Do you mean I must make the user hit some dummy link `<a href="setupForm.htm">kindly start up this app</a>` before he can start working?

Comment: (3) I would still love an explanation on what failed in my code, what Spring expected, what @SessionAttributes does and when. Or some reference to where it's all explained. Since it's not on the javadoc.

Comment: my 1st comment it should read: "with no @RequestMapping - it has NO arguments" -- this system will not let me edit my comments.

Comment: You do have to annotate your method with @RequestMapping in order for it to be processed as a controller method.  Spring tries to match method signatures exactly, so in the lack of data, it will use the one with the least amount of information.  If you have more data (in your case, you actually will have the form after the first method), it will match those more specific methods.  As for (2), this is always the case regardless of what controller strategy you use - the first hit to the link needs to set up the form (now, that's not to say it cannot be (continued at (2)).

Comment: (2) a link such as /book/bookForm.htm?bookId=345.  In that case, you can use the parameter mapping as follows:     @RequestMapping(value = "/book/bookForm.htm", params="bookId")
    public ModelAndView setupForm(@RequestParam(value="bookId", required = true) final int bookId) {
 Book book = bookService.getBook(bookId);
 ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
 // I don't remember the exact syntax here - pretending its a java.util.Map.
 modelMap.put("book", book);

 return new ModelAndView("bookForm", modelMap);
    }

Comment: Reference link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller

Answer (score -2):

Add these code lines in the controller class

```
@ModelAttribute("book")
    public UserObject getBookObject() {
        return new Book();

    }
```

While Using SessuinAttributes , U need to Add object in session by using above mentioned code