# SpringMVC using @ExceptionHandler HTTP Status 500 - Expected session attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to use **@exceptionhandler** to capture an **HTTP Status 500 - Expected session attribute**. I would like to return a message to the same page i am on showing the user the error.

Can someone point me to an example on how i can handle this exception and return a message to the view instead of redirecting to another page.

This is what i have so far however the item in the view is not getting set with the error message;

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpSessionRequiredException.class)
    public RedirectView handleHttpSessionRequiredException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
    {
        logger.info("In the handleHttpSessionRequiredException Handler Method");
        String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView(referrer);
        redirectView.addStaticAttribute("errorMessage","Execute A Query Then Retry");
        return redirectView;
    }
```

**View**

```
<label id="errorMessage" name="errorMessage">${errorMessage}</label>
```

Comment: I think what you can do is check if the attribute is null throw a BusinessException which you can catch in @ExceptionHandler and retun to te same view with added messages. See this  https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/exceptions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757198/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the referer and forward or redirect to it. E.g.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpSessionRequiredException.class)
public String (HttpServletRequest request) {
    String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
    ...
    FlashMap flashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);
flashMap.put("errorMessage","Execute A Query Then Retry");
    return "redirect:/my/url";
}
```

The redirect URL is relative to the application path. You can extract it from the referer.

Comment: i am also trying  redirectView.addStaticAttribute("errorMessage", ex.getMessage()) in the  Exception handler however it is not setting the message in the view. The view has a label <label id="errorMessage" name ="errorMessage">${errorMessage}</label>

Comment: @dev_darin For how to set attributes on redirect look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-redirect-attributes)

Comment: if i change the method type to return anything else other than RedirectView the exception is not going into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a ModelAndView from an @ExceptionHandler method by doing something like the following.

```
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
public ModelAndView handleIOException(IOException ex) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("someObject", new SomeObject());
    modelAndView.setViewName("someView");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

The problem is figuring out the current page you were on before. To my knowledge, there isn't a way to get the current model and view from inside an ExceptionHandler method so you won't have a good way of knowing what view to use.

I think your best bet is to catch and handle the Exception in your controller.

Comment: This means i would have to redirect to an exception page?