# Preserving file uploaded between views

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am using Spring MVC in a web application. I have a view where I allow users to upload a file, and I would like to preserve this file between subsequent views, so in the controller action I add it to the model of my next view:

```
@RequestMapping("/loadFile")
    public String loadFile(
            Model model, 
            @RequestParam(required = true) CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) 
{
//some process
model.addAttribute("file", uploadedFile);
}
```

So my next view should have the file "accesible". I tried to replicate the form of my file upload view and then assign this file value to the file input like this:

But this assigns a value of `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@57836c9d` or something similar, and it does not work.

How would you do to propagate this file between views likeso?

Comment: What you are seeing is the value of the `toString()` method. In your second view, do you want to be able to see the path of the file in the input field?

Comment: I want to have access to this file in other controller actions besides the ones that receives the request from the first form.

Comment: Why don't you save it to disk and access it in later requests?

Comment: Because I run the risk of not deleting it afterwards, as the user can just close the current page then I wouldn't ever know when to delete it...

Comment: You can use a `HttpSessionListener` for that. Store the `CommonsMultipartFile` in the session.

Comment: Mmm can you expand a little on that please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Spring controller, you have access to the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). This object is used to store information between user requests. You do this with the `getAttribute(String)` and `setAttribute(String, Object)` methods.

If you want the uploaded file to be available across multiple requests, through the `CommonsMultipartFile` interface, you can store that object in the session. For example:

```
HttpSession session = ... // get the session, you have it in your handler method
CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile = ...; // same as above
session.setAttribute("UPLOADED_FILE", uploadedFile);
```

Now as long as your session is valid, ie. hasn't timed out or been invalidated, any Controller or servlet can access this object

```
CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile = session.getAttribute("UPLOADED_FILE");
```

Spring has an annotation for this in `@SessionAttributes`, for which you can look at an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757198/spring-framework-3-and-session-attributes), but I don't like it.

You might be interested in the [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) interface for managing the attributes in the session.

Comment: I thought of that solution but my files can be quite big (up to 15mb). Wouldn't this be a problem?

Comment: @MichelReap The `CommonsMultipartFile` doesn't actually store the bytes in memory, it has a reference to the persisted file (you serlvet container saves it to disk) and retrieves the bytes when needed, so no.

Comment: I didn't know that, that sounds like the perfect solution then. Thanks!

Comment: @MichelReap You could do some more research about how Apache Commons does the multipart file stuff. The Spring module you're using is built on top of it..

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am getting Error While sending List of Multipart files in session Can you help me plz..!