# How to use @SessionAtribute in spring MVC

Tags: jsp, session, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

can someone give a reference for @sessionattribute annotation in Spring MCV.

How to save an object and get that object.

Comment: Read [Spring Framework 3 and session attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757198/spring-framework-3-and-session-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Refer Spring documentation at below link.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib

Below link also may help you.

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntex:

@SessionAttributes(value = "customer")

This is a link:
http://www.programsji.com/spring/SessionAttributes