# spring mvc with ssl enabled - no session attribute available

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, ssl

I have a problem with my spring MVC project. On my local machine, my project runs without SSL configured in spring security and form submits works fine. But if I enable SSL and upload the project to my server, I get on each form submit the following exception:

> org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session
>   attribute 'xxxxx'
>     org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:114)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:758)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter.doFilter(DandelionFilter.java:138)
>     org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.gzip.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:85)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     de.eseven.bleckmannschulze.profiler.core.security.AjaxSessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(AjaxSessionTimeoutFilter.java:38)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

I have no idea watts going wrong here. Login and normal get requests works, but if I submit a form with a session attribute, I get this exception.

It would be nice, to get some hints, where I can research for my problem.

Comment: The problem is not likely related to SSL. Different version of Spring on your server? There's a similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757198/spring-framework-3-and-session-attributes

Comment: The only different to my local test machine is that on my online server there is an apache before tomcat and connected thru ajp to the tomcat.

Comment: After more testing.
SSL and Apache unintressted. without ssl configured and with direct access to tomcat, i get the same error. So there are no difference between my local machine and the server. same application war-file.
same java jre and tomcat 7 on both systems.
i have no more idea where i can search for the problem

Comment: On my local machine i have no problems with the session attributes, only on the server

Comment: This answer should solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/2757449/1594449

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. I solved my problem now.. the problem was, that i use a custom session attribute store and annotated my security config with `@EnableWebMvcSecurity`.

Here on my local machine, my custom store replace the spring security store. But on the server its in other way around. There the spring security store replace my custom store. I don't know way its declared in different order. Now i changed to `@EnableWebSecurity` everything works fine!